# How to display and replace Employee data?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, do-while

I am lost at the case 3 part--updating the employee information by browsing the structure and checking if the input matches or not.

> The question:
>
> "Prompt the user for the employee identification number using a
>   do-while loop. While the number is not found in the employee array,
>   keep prompting the user."
>
> "Once the number is found, display the current salary for the employee
>   with that identification number and prompt the user to input the new
>   salary. Replace the old salary with the input value."

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 4

struct employee_data{
    int Age;
    int Int_Num;
    double Salary;
};

int main(void){

    int option = 0;
    int NOE = 0;
    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n");`enter code here`

    struct employee_data emp[SIZE];
        // Employee_ID
    int i;
    do {
        // Print the option list
        printf("\n1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");

        printf("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
        printf("4. Remove Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");

        // Capture input to option variable
        scanf("%d",&option);
        printf("\n");

        switch (option) {
            case 0: // Exit the program
                    printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!\n");
                    break;
            case 1: // Display Employee Data
                            // @IN-LAB

                    printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                    printf("======  ======= ==========\n");
                    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
                        printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].Int_Num, emp[i].Age,emp[i]
                    // /printf("\n");
                    }
                    //  printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf", emp[1].Age, emp[1].Int_Num,emp[1]
                    // Use "%6d%9d%11.2lf" formatting in a
                    // printf statement to display
                    // employee id, age and salary of
                    // all  employees using a loop construct

                    // The loop construct will be run for SIZE times
                    // and will only display Employee data
                    // where the EmployeeID is > 0
                    // printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 2: // Adding Employee

                    // @IN-LAB

                    //   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    printf("Adding Employee\n");
                    printf("===============\n");
                    if(NOE < SIZE){
                        // printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n"
                        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &emp[NOE].Int_Num);
                        printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                        scanf("%d", &emp[NOE].Age);
                        printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                        scanf("%11lf", &emp[NOE].Salary);

                        NOE++;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n");
                    }
                    // Check for limits on the array and add employee
                    // data accordingly.}
                    break;

                    int number = 0;
            case 3: printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
                    printf("======================\n");
                    do {

                        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &number);
                        if(number == emp[NOE].Int_Num){
                            printf("The current salary is %11lf", emp[NOE].Salary);

                            }
                            //  else{
                    }while (number != emp[NOE].Int_Num);
                    break;
```

Comment: `if(number == emp[NOE].Int_Num){` : `NOE` can't use for this.

Comment: Also `printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].Int_Num, emp[i].Age,emp[i]` : The code is missing.

Comment: `int number = 0;
        case 3:` --> `case 3: ; int number = 0;`

Comment: Please try to indent your code, so it's easier for you or anyone to check

Comment: What is the `enter code here` at line 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following changes. Firstly compare all the current employees with the given input. If there is no match, then prompt the user to ask for employee identification number again.

```
case 3: printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
                printf("======================\n");
                int flag = 0;
                do{
                    printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                    scanf("%d", &number);
                    int i;
                    for( i =0; i<NOE ; i++)   //checking for each current employee
                    {
                        if(number == emp[i].Int_Num)
                        {
                            printf("The current salary is %11lf", emp[i].Salary);
                            printf("\nInput new salary");
                            scanf("%11lf", &emp[i].Salary);
                            flag = 1; 
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                 } while (flag == 0);
                break;
```